# Dynamic form field in Django REST

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form where the user can create a blog. The form will have a title, one to many authors, and content. For the authors part, I'd like to have an input autocomplete search box (like stackoverflow's tags search box) that will add authors to the blog. I know how to create the frontend look of this, but as far as using Django's REST framework to add the authors in my model I don't know how to do that.

Models:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    content     = models.TextField()
    created_at  = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class StoryAuthor(models.Model):
    story   = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How do I go through each added author from the input and add it into my StoryAuthor model? So for example, one story should look like this:

```
id title         content     created_at
1  Hello world   blah, blah  2019-06-04


story  user
1      John
1      Jack
1      Brad
```

As far as the input box, the data would look like this: "John, Jack, Brad" how can I use Django's REST to have a serializer/endpoint that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumming you are working with [Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#api-reference), below could be the approach.

Just add [ManyToMany Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) in your Story model:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    content     = models.TextField()
    created_at  = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    #new field
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='StoryAuthor')
```

Then in your serialzer, add author field to Serialzer ([CustomSerialzer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields)) and write User Serialzer (if you don't already have it):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    authors = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        ...
```

**Note:** 
If you don't plan to add extra fields to your `StoryAuthor`, you don't need to write the StoryAuthor class yourself. Just add the authors field in Story class without 'through' argument and Django's ORM will take care of pivot table.

Comment: I see, very interesting. So how would I send the data to my endpoint? For example, how does the serializer recognize the multiple authors through something like: "John, Jack, Brad"

Comment: It would be list of user id's in JSON, eg `{ 'authors' : [2,4,5] }`
assuming 2,4,5 are ids of users John, Jack, Brad respectively

Comment: I see, so it would be an array?

Comment: Also, in your last note, if I don't add through, what will happen? Will the data be saved as an array inside the authors field? Or will the entire data be duplicated for each author?

Comment: Sorry for late response. 
Yes, it would be an array.
If you don't use through, data will be saved as an array of Users in authors field.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `read_only=True` ? It doesn't let me add any authors?